# How to get a Discord Bot to return the formatted name of a Channel?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm attempting to create a Discord bot using Discord.py for a server I'm in, I'm trying to get the bot to mention (blue links) other channels in the server. I thought it would have been using something like `discord.TextChannel.name`, `discord.TextChannel.mention`. But neither of those work, they only return something along the lines of "`<property object at 0x03CE8B68>`".

Code:

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')
client = discord.Client()
token = <token>


@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)


@bot.command()
async def mentionChan(ctx):
    await ctx.send(ctx.guild.get_channel('662129928463974411').mention)


client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@botclient.command()   
async def mentionChan(ctx):
    await ctx.send(ctx.guild.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID).mention)
```

This will mention the channel with the given id. You can get the id of a channel by right clicking a channel and selecting "Copy ID". This is only possible after you have turned on developer mode at the appearance tab in User Settings.

`ctx.guild.text_channels` will give you a list of all the text channels in the server if you want to use that.

Comment: Not sure if I am doing something wrong, but this doesn't work for me. Typing the command on the server doesn't actually make the bot do anything.

Comment: And you're sure you changed CHANNEL_ID with the right ID? If it's not sending anything then it's most likely throwing an AttributeError because get_channel has returned a None type. This code (with CHANNEL_ID replaced) works for me as is.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/421077230861418498/678626217402040346/Screenshot_2020-02-16_at_16.38.04.png

Comment: Yeah, I even made a test command that would just return what the user types, doesn't even work. I think I might be missing something.

Comment: Are none of your commands working? Or only commands that try to send something? It could be that you set up the permissions for your bot incorrectly, see if it has the required permissions to actually send messages,

Comment: I thought it might have been that and went to check, the settings **were** wrong, but even when I changed them the bot wouldn't send messages. I have to be missing something completely obvious here.

Comment: Can you add the complete code of your bot, excluding your token, to your original post? Then I can take a look and see what might be wrong.

Comment: @AustynHoward Are you using a on_message() function before your commands?

Comment: Remove ```client = discord.Client()``` and change the last line to ```bot.run(token)```. That should fix it!